What law may you break with "fake" fingerprints?
There are many situations where fingerprints are used for identification.  The most famous example is upon arrest, the EU are introducing them at the border, companies may fingerprint their staff and devices use fingerprint recognition for authentication.
One can purchase "fake" fingerprints that provide a unique pattern that is advertised as being more secure than the "natural" ones.  Under what circumstances could one be committing a crime just by using these?
To be clear on what I am asking, take the body parts the face, the genitals and the finger prints.  Faces have been used for a long time to establish identity at a border, and I would expect many countries to have laws requiring one to show present your face in some circumstances, and it seems likely that intentional attempts to obscure ones face at the border could be outlawed without any requirement for another crime.  I am fairly sure the same is not true of genitalia.  Even if the EU introduced a genitalia based identity system to the millimeter wave scanners at the border it would be legal to attempt to obscure ones genitalia as long as one used your real passport to cross the border.  What about fingerprints?  I also wonder about DNA.

Doesn't that depend exclusively on where you use the fake fingerprints? If you do so at a EU border check you presumaly broke EU immigration/ border control laws. If a company checks them you broke the companies rules, which in general are not laws, etc.

What are they used for?

How is it more secure? Surely it's easier to steal and use the fake finger print than it is to find an actual fingerprint, know who left it, copy, and make another fake one? Burglar says "ooh here's the phone, and here's the fake print to unlock it."

@quarague That is basically the question.  In your example, an answer with the specific law that would be broken if one wore these at an EU border crossing would be valid.

@WeatherVane The web site says "As humans, we are constantly touching things and leaving fingerprints everywhere. It is easy to steal fingerprints from anyone. Fingerprints are also irreplaceable. If a person’s fingerprints get captured and leaked, the person can never use them as security keys anymore."

...and if someone steals your fake print (or you lose it) how do you explain to those asking for print ID that you need to change it? Exactly how great is the risk of someone taking your grease print and faking your ID?

@WeatherVane I am certainly not arguing that this particular product has any real world utility.  The core question is to what extent can one obscure ones biometric information against surveillance.  Is there some general law that prevents obscuring ones biometric information?  Are fingerprints special because of their long history in law enforcement?  Would it depend on the reason you are doing it, or is the action itself sufficient to be illegal?

When you do so dishonestly intending to obtain an advantage
Fake fingerprints or anything else used in this matter is a textbook example of fraud.
When it amounts to an unlawful attempt to deceive the government
For example, if you used them at a border crossing.

Specific laws, particularly in the case of a border crossing would add to this answer.  Would the deceit require one deceiving the government about who you are, or would just deceiving the government about what your finger prints are be enough.

UK's Immigration Act deals with deception and false documents. Plainly, fake fingerprints attempt to conceal your true identity.

@WeatherVane Not if you use your real passport.

@User65535 which is bound to your real fingerprints.

@Trish My passport does not have fingerprint information.

@User65535 then your passport tells that to the border patrol and they don't even fingerprint you but do another validity check.

@Trish The USA fingerprints all travellers crossing its borders to compare against the next time they cross
